# Windows phone: How do I globalize/localize application title text in App list and tile

Tags: localization, windows-phone-8, title, globalization

I use resource string for text appear in xaml pages by using these
{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AppName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}

But where and how do I globalize application title in App list and Tile? Is it in WMAppManefist.xml? I tried the above syntax in App Title and token Title but don't seem to work.

Comment: Check this article: [How to localize an app title for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I still can't make it working. I followed the instruction from the link and created AppResLib.dll, AppResLib.dll.0409.mui, and AppResLib.dll.0804.mui. With the language setting on device, either English (United States) or PRC (China), I got same result. The name is App list is still in English text and name in Tile is "@\Data\Programs\{.". Very wierd. Also I have the @ AppResLib.dll,-100 and @ AppResLib.dll,-200 in WMAppManifest.xml. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Having followed an article provided by Alaa Masound be sure to use:

```
@AppResLib.dll,-101
```

instead of:

```
@AppResLib.dll,-200
```

as your tile title, as defined in Microsoft resource dll template (AppResLib.rc):

```
#define AppTitle                        100
#define AppTileTitle                    101
```

So the reason for the problem is a discrepancy between Microsoft source code and its description.